# PHP displaying multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array similar to this:

```
$suppliers = array(
  'Utility Warehouse' => array('Gas' => array(0,0), 'Electricty' => array(0,0)),
  'British Gas' => array('Gas' => array(93,124), 'Electricty' => array(93,124)),
  'Eon' => array('Gas' => array(93,124), 'Electricty' => array(93,124))
);
```

How can display the information as follows

```
Utility Warehouse
Gas: 0-0 Electricity 0-0

British Gas
Gas: 93-134 Electricity: 93-134

Eon
Gas: 93-124 Electricity: 93-134
```

You can see how the displayed data corresponds to the data in the array. I've tried this:

```
foreach($suppliers as $a){
    echo $a[0];
}
```

But this does nothing. CONFUSED!

Comment: What information about PHP arrays or foreach loops made you expect that that code was going to produce those results?  I'm confused as to how you imagined that the code you have would output results formatted with newlines, colons, and hyphens.

Comment: I wasn't expecting all the colons, newlines etc.... that was an example of what I was hoping would output the suppliers name for example

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Well, for future reference, the `echo` language construct only takes strings as an argument, tho it will attempt to convert things (integers, etc.) to strings.  Arrays don't have an automatic method to convert to strings so you can't `echo` an whole array.  Check out the examples [here](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php 

foreach($suppliers as $supplier => $category) {
    echo $supplier . '<br />';
    foreach($category as $cat_name => $values_arr) {
        echo $cat_name . ': ' . implode('-', $values_arr) . '<br /><br />';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
foreach($suppliers as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . "<br />";
    foreach($value as $a => $price) {
        echo $a .': '. $price[0].'-'.$price[1];
    }
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code to achieve what you want would be following, but i suggest you brush up on your PHP skills a bit more, as this is a trivial task.

```
foreach($suppliers as $name => $data){
    echo $name . '<br/>';
    foreach($data as $utility => $value){
        echo $utility . ': ' . $value[0] . '-' . $value[1] . ' ';
    }
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as everyone else (I'm too slow).  Here's a working example: http://codepad.org/PDPEjAGJ

Also, everyone who answered this question, me included, is guilty of spoonfeeding.  Ahh well, the things I'll do for points! :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple recursive function one can use. I found it and modified it for presentation purposes. The original source is in the comments.

```
function print_a($array, $level=0){
  # source: https://thisinterestsme.com/php-using-recursion-print-values-multidimensional-array/
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    # If $value is an array.
    if(is_array($value)){
      echo str_repeat("-", $level). "<br>{$key}<br>\r\n";
      # We need to loop through it.
      print_a($value, $level + 1);
    } else{
      # It is not an array, so print it out.
      echo str_repeat("-", $level) . "{$key}: {$value}<br>\r\n";
    }
  }
} # END FUNCTION print_a
```