# How to display this multidimensial array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to display the following code such that the car models (Nissan, Mercedes, Ford) would be an `<h1>`, the years would be an `<h3>`, and the sub-array items would be in a `<ul>`. How would I do this?

```
$cars = array (
        array(
            "Nissan",
            2012,
            array (
                "power steering",
                "a/c",
            )
        ),

        array(
            "Mercedes",
            2013,
            array (
                "power steering",
                "leather seats",
                "sunroof"
            )
        ),

        array(
            "Ford",
            2010,
            array (
                "power steering",
                "a/c",
                "power windows",
                "window locks"
            )
        )
);
```

Comment: You need to make an attempt if you want to be helped.

Comment: Please check the reference. I hope its work!!!
[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808642/php-displaying-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Hi @mkb, welcome to stackoverflow! It looks like you have a good start, but you haven't shared a real attempt at solving this problem. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the best answers to your questions. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We might just want to define a `string` here in a `foreach`, then constantly `append` to it, as we walk through our array:

```
$cars = array(
    array(
        "Nissan",
        2012,
        array(
            "power steering",
            "a/c",
        ),
    ),

    array(
        "Mercedes",
        2013,
        array(
            "power steering",
            "leather seats",
            "sunroof",
        ),
    ),

    array(
        "Ford",
        2010,
        array(
            "power steering",
            "a/c",
            "power windows",
            "window locks",
        ),
    ),
);

$html = '';
foreach ($cars as $key => $car) {
    $html .= '<h1>' . $car[0] . '</h1>';
    $html .= '<h3>' . $car[1] . '</h3>';
    $html .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($car[2] as $key => $attr) {
        $html .= '<li>' . $attr . '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
}

echo $html;
```

#### Output

```
<h1>Nissan</h1><h3>2012</h3><ul><li>power steering</li><li>a/c</li></ul><h1>Mercedes</h1><h3>2013</h3><ul><li>power steering</li><li>leather seats</li><li>sunroof</li></ul><h1>Ford</h1><h3>2010</h3><ul><li>power steering</li><li>a/c</li><li>power windows</li><li>window locks</li></ul>
```

#### Advice

[Vivek_23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4964822/vivek-23) advises that:

> Just implode the li part.

Based on which, our code would probably look like as simple as:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    $html .= '<h1>' . $car[0] . '</h1>';
    $html .= '<h3>' . $car[1] . '</h3>';
    $html .= '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $car[2]) . '</li></ul>';
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: thanks so much! I altered it a bit to change each `$html .=` to just `echo` and it that's working well. thanks!

Comment: @Emma Just implode the `li` part.